# Jquery validate is not working on boolean value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Hi so I have a modal with a bool value from my Model for site occupied, for reason it is causing my validate form to be ignored and I cant work out why.  if I remove the code block for   Occupied When Visited the validation works fine.  I dont need to validate this check box so is there any way I can ignore it in validate? I have tried using ignore: siteOccupied, no luck, tried giving it its own class  ignore: ".ignore", no luck either.  any help would be appreciated

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="submitRecordModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="submitRecordModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="invalidModel">
                <span>
                    Please fill out all fields marked with a *
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="submitRecordModalLabel">Site Visit Check</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="submitRecordForm">
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label fw-bolder">Debt</label>

                        <div class="form-check mb-3 ignore">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="siteOccupied" name="siteOccupied" asp-for="@Model.Account.OccupiedWhenVisited">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="siteOccupied">
                                Occupied When Visited
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-check mb-3">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="loiLeft" asp-for="@Model.Account.DebtChecks["LoiLeft"]">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="loiLeft">
                                LOI Left
                            </label>
                        </div>
                                                
                        <div class="row gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center mb-3">
                            <div class="col-auto">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="contactCustomer" asp-for="@Model.Account.DebtChecks["ContactWithCustomer"]">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        Contact With Customer
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactName" name="contactName" asp-for="Account.ContactName">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" form="submitRecordForm" asp-page-handler="SavetoDB" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submitRecordForm").validate({
                ignore: ".ignore",
                rules: {
                    contactName: {
                        required: "#contactCustomer:checked"
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    contactName: {
                        required: "Please enter some data",
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You're using ASP with Unobtrusive Validation, therefore you cannot also call `.validate()` because it will be completely ignored.  When using Unobtrusive with ASP, you need to follow the validation practices and guidelines as per the ASP documentation.  If you'd rather configure the jQuery Validate plugin directly, then you cannot also use Unobtrusive, which will over ride.

Comment: thankyou i feel like an idiot, removed the Unobtrusive src and it works now